# Is the $24$ game NP-complete?

Tags: computer-science

The $24$ game is as follows. Four numbers are drawn; the player's objective is to make $24$ from the four numbers using the four basic arithmetic operations (in any order) and parentheses however one pleases.

Consider the following generalization. Given $n+1$ numbers, determine whether the last one can be obtained from the first $n$ using elementary arithmetical operations as above. This problem admits succinct certificates so is in NP.

Is it NP-complete$?$

Comment: This sounds pretty similar to subset sum (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem), which is NP complete.

Comment: Can we *not* use LaTeX if the formula is simple enough like 'n+1'? And $NP$ is definitely wrong — at least use $\mathrm{NP}$.

Comment: @Simon: Similar, yes; but can you show a reduction from it?

Comment: Not yet, which is why I left a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: @Akhil: Looks like we're going to need a hint (I'm assuming you already know the answer.. :)

Comment: No, I don't know the answer. I thought there might be a reduction from subset-sum, but didn't see how to do it.

Comment: Should all numbers be different? (no, I do not know the result anyway, it's just out of curiosity)

Comment: Not necessarily, but if it makes it any easier, that's fine too.

Comment: @313 You should only edit such ancient posts if the edit is important. Your edit was far too minor!

Answer (score 5):

This is still WIP. There are a few missing details, still I think it's better than nothing. Feel free to edit in the missing details.

Given a problem of `SUBSET-SUM`. We have a set of `A`={a<sub>1</sub>,a<sub>2</sub>,...,a<sub>n</sub>} numbers, and another number `s`. The question we're seeking answer to is, whether or not there's a subset of `A` whose sum is `s`.

I'm assuming that the 24-game allows you to use rational numbers. Even if it doesn't, I think that it is possible to emulate rational numbers up to denominator of size `p` with integers.

We know that `SUBSET-SUM` is NP-complete even for integers only. I think the `SUBSET-SUM` problem is `NP`-hard even if you allow treating each a<sub>i</sub> as a negative number. That is even if `A` is of the form `A`={a<sub>1</sub>,-a<sub>1</sub>,a<sub>2</sub>,-a<sub>2</sub>,...,a<sub>n</sub>,-a<sub>n</sub>}. This is still a wrinkle I need to iron out in this reduction.

Obviously, if there's a subset of `A` with sum `s`, then there's a solution to the `24`-problem for how to reach using `A` to `s`. The solution is only using the `+` sign.

The problem is, what happens if there's no solution which only uses the `+` sign, but there is a solution which uses other arithmetic operations.

Let us consider the following problem. Let's take a prime `p` which is larger than `n`, the total number of elements in `A`. Given an oracle which solves the `24`-problem, and a `SUBSET-SUM` problem of `A`={a<sub>1</sub>,a<sub>2</sub>,...,a<sub>n</sub>} and `s`. We'll ask the oracle to solve the `24`-problem on

> `A`={a<sub>1</sub>+(1/p),a<sub>2</sub>+(1/p),...,a<sub>n</sub>+(1/p)}

for the following values:

> s<sub>1</sub>=s+1/p,s<sub>2</sub>=s+2/p,...,s<sub>n</sub>=s+n/p.

If the solution includes multiplication, we will have a denominator larger than `p` in the end result, and thus we will not be able to reach any s<sub>i</sub>.

Given an arithmetric expression that contains a<sub>i</sub>a<sub>j</sub>=x+(1/p<sup>2</sup>), It is impossible that the denominator p<sup>2</sup> would "cancel" out, since there are at most `n` elements in the summation, and thus the numerator would never reach `p`, since `p>n`.

THIS IS NOT QUIT RIGHT! The expression a<sub>i</sub>a<sub>j</sub>-a<sub>k</sub>a<sub>l</sub> will be an integer, and therefor our oracle might return answer which includes two multiplications one negative and one positive.

What about division? How can we be sure no division will occur. Find another prime `q` which is different than p, and larger than the largest a<sub>i</sub> times `n`. Multiply all answers by `q`. The set `A` will be

> `A`={qa<sub>1</sub>+(1/p),qa<sub>2</sub>+(1/p),...,qa<sub>n</sub>+(1/p)}

We will look for the following values:

> s<sub>1</sub>=qs+1/p,s<sub>2</sub>=qs+2/p,...,s<sub>n</sub>=qs+n/p.

In that case, a<sub>i</sub>/a<sub>j</sub> will be smaller than the minimal element in `A`, and therefor the end result which will contains a<sub>i</sub>/a<sub>j</sub> will never be one of the s<sub>i</sub> we're looking for.

Comment: I don't understand your proof - just because our oracle gives a solution using multiplication does *not* mean there's not also a solution using addition; in the same vein, just because there is a solution to the subset-sum doesn't mean it's the same 24-solution our oracle will give.  Is this fact dealt with somehow?  (if we change the oracle to give *every* solution, the reduction is simple:  append a bunch of 0's and ask the oracle for all the solutions; then check if one of the solutions is of the form `a1 + 0*a2 + a3 + a4 + 0*5 + ...`.  But, that is not the question)

Comment: @BlueRaja, If I understood the question correctly, the reduction I need to provide is, given an oracle which solves the 24-problem in polynomial time, show it is possible to solve an NPC problem in polynomial time. This will prove the problem is NP-hard. It is easy to see that if we only allow the use of addition in the 24-problem, then it's parallel to SUBSET-SUM. I'm trying to show we can "force" the 24-problem oracle solver not to use multiplication or division. Is that clearer?

Comment: Oh, I see where the confusion lies:  you are assuming that the numbers $a_1, a_2, .., a_n$ given in the problem are restricted to integers, but the oracle which solves the problem is allowed to input rational numbers?  Is that correct?

Comment: This is an interesting avenue, but I'm not entirely sure about the details. For instance, the first statement about multiplication -- is it possible that sum of the denominators cancel?

Comment: @BlueRaja, This is exactly what I assume. However my assumption is correct, since SUBSET-SUM is known to be NP-complete even on integers. I'll fix that in my answer.

Comment: @Akhill, it is impossible that the denominators will cancel, since `p>n` and is prime, and even if we add up all the numbers in A we will never get anything which divides `p`. I'll add that to the question. And thanks for the valuable input!

Comment: Couldn't you cancel a 1/(p^2) term by subtracting another product?

Comment: @yatima2975 Good point. Maybe I'm on the wrong track. I need to think if there's a way to avoid that.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few subtleties that will probably effect the final answer.

1. Are we required to find the solution, or merely establish existence? By analogy, determining if a number has a prime factorization is trivial, but finding its prime factorization is hard.
2. Is the runtime being measured in terms of {a_1,...,a_n,s} or {log(a_i),...,log(a_n),log(s)}? By analogy, SUBSET-SUM is in P in the first case, but NP-complete in the second case.

Comment: 1. Existence is enough (I wasn't talking about the function problem). 2. The second.  Well, actually we have to add $n$ to it (I don't think we should take $\log n$).

Comment: @Jeff, SUBSET-SUM is never in P. The kind of problems you can never solve in polynomial time, regardless of the actual numbers given to you is called strongly NP-complete http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_NP-complete

Comment: Oops, it's Jeremy not Jeff.
And BTW Jeremy, this kind of post should be in a comment I think.

Comment: Neither of those questions make sense to me - this is not an algorithm, it's a yes or no question.  Of course an answer *exists:*  it's either yes, or no.

Comment: @ Elazar: Agreed, but I didn't have enough reputation to leave a comment.

Comment: @BlueRaja: I mean find the solution, in the yes case, not just the establish a yes/no answer. It's entirely possible that a polynomial-time algorithm could exist which answers "This board is solvable" correctly, yet no such algorithm exists which can actually output what the nature of that solution is.

Answer (score 1):

It's worth considering a few ways of showing that the problem is neither in P, nor NPC. I've marked this answer "community wiki", so please feel free to add suggestions and flesh out ideas here.

Based on my experience playing the 24 game, it seems that most combinations of numbers are solvable. If we could formalize this, we could show that the 24 game is not NPC. Formally, consider the `2^n` inputs of length `n`. If all but polynomially-many of them solvable, then the language is sparse and cannot be NPC (unless P=NP).