# When the 24 Game is solvable given the four cards?

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, number-theory, galois-theory, puzzle

Consider the [24 Game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24_Game) with a deck of cards that forms a set $ \Omega = \{1, 2, ..., 13\}$, and we try to compute 24 using addition, subtraction, division and multiplication in Rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$ for any set $E$ that is 4 samples *with* replacement from $\Omega$. Now, is there a general condition, maybe from the group theory, that specifies the conditions that $E$ must satisfy so that it is solvable?

It is trivial to actually test if any specific $E$ is solvable, by an exhaustive brute force search for all possible combinations of arithmetic operations and their order. However, is it also possible to determine solvability *without* such a brute force attempt? My hunch is, this could be answered using number theory, or Galois theory.

This might relate to [another post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/631/is-the-24-game-np-complete), but I couldn't understand the answer in that post. Maybe it was unrelated.